# How to write a reusable function inside an object

Tags: javascript

I'm making a little guessing game in JavaScript. I wrote a function that returns a letter to indicate the `result`. It returns a `w` for "won," `l` for "lost,", and `d` for "drawn".

Every time I add a new match, I have to repeat the function that calculates the `result` property. How can I make it so that I don't have to repeat the logic that calculates the result for each match?

```
{
    name: 'Elmer',
    matches: [{
        against: 'Roger',
        score_for: 3,
        score_against: 1,
        result: function () {
            if (this.score_for > this.score_against) {
                return 'w';
            } else if (this.score_for < this.score_against) {
                return 'l';
            } else {
                return 't';
            }
        }
    }, {
        against: 'Marvin',
        score_for: 1,
        score_against: 1
    }]
}
```

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to anything until you call the function, unless you use `bind`.

Comment: I think we need more context though. It's hard to tell how to refactor this without seeing the actual logic of the game, and how it is structured. You might need a different data structure and make use of closures.

Comment: @elclanrs I want to do `obj.matches.push()` to add a match. But I don't want to have to define the result function each time. So `obj.matches.push({ against: 'Buggs', score_for: 1, score_against: 0 })` then I would want it to have the `result` available automatically.

Comment: Post some more code, it will help, as-is your question isn't very useful, there's no context, it's just a plain object that we don't how it connects with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it so that I don't have to repeat the logic that calculates the result for each match?

With minimal changes to your existing code, just declare a named function that contains the logic:

```
function result() {
    if (this.score_for > this.score_against) {
        return 'w';
    } else if (this.score_for < this.score_against) {
        return 'l';
    } else {
        return 't';
    }
}
```

and then you  assign it as a property to each match:

```
var game = {
    name: 'Elmer',
    matches: [{
        against: 'Roger',
        score_for: 3,
        score_against: 1,
        result: result
    }, {
        against: 'Marvin',
        score_for: 1,
        score_against: 1
    }]
};
```

Functions are just a special kind of object, so you can assign, pass and return them like any other value.

---

Alternatively you could define the function such that it *accepts* a match as argument instead:

```
function getResult(match) {
    if (match.score_for > match.score_against) {
        return 'w';
    } else if (match.score_for < match.score_against) {
        return 'l';
    } else {
        return 't';
    }
}
```

and later, instead of doing `someMatch.result()`, you do `getResult(someMatch)`.

---

Some resources to learn more about functions and objects:

- [MDN - Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
- [quirksmode.org - Functions](http://quirksmode.org/js/function.html)
- [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Hmmmm @JumbalayaWanton Why did you **change** your original question? Now my answer does not help at all....

Comment: @qwertynl I changed it because people were getting confused about which question to answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using the module pattern:

For example:

```
var Player = (function() {
    function Player (name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.matches = [];
    }

    Player.prototype.setMatches = function (matches) {
        this.matches = matches;
    };

    Player.prototype.getGamesPlayed = function () {
        return this.matches.length;
    };

    Player.prototype.getMatches = function () {
        return this.matches;
    };

    return Player;
})();
```

Then you *could* do something like this:

```
var elmo = new Player('Elmo');
elmo.setMatches({
        against: 'Roger',
        score_for: 3,
        score_against: 1
    }, {
        against: 'Marvin',
        score_for: 1,
        score_against: 1
    });
/// etc...
```